# Why warning "forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false'" disappears when using not operator?

Tags: c++, warnings

Consider the following code compiled with Visual Studio 2015:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

void foo( bool b )
{
    std::cout << b;
}

int main()
{
    int a;

    foo( a = 2 );       // getting warning #4800
    foo( !(a = 2) );    // not getting any warning

    return 0;
}
```

`foo( a = 2 )` produces warning 4800 `'int': forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false'`, fine.

But `foo( !(a = 2) )` does not produce the warning. Why? At some point there has been a int to bool cast!

Comment: A compiler is not guaranteed any warnings to you.  Outright C++ errors, yes, warnings, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo(a = 2)` is equivalent to `bool b = (a = 2)`. The expression `a = 2` returns an `a`, so it is equivalent to

```
a = 2;
bool b = a; //Conversion of 'int' to 'bool' -> Warning!
```

`foo(!(a = 2))` is equivalent to `bool b = !(a = 2)`. The expression `a = 2` returns `a`:

```
a = 2;
bool b = !a; //'!a' is legal => It returns a bool -> No warning!
```

Note that you can apply `operator!` to an `int`, which negates the `int`, and so returns a `bool`. That's why there is no performance warning.

Comment: This is all correct, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @PeteBecker could you explain why please? Did I misunderstand anything?

Comment: @Rakete1111: you might want to add that `!` *can* operate on `int` (i.e., no casting) and still returns bool..

Comment: @lorro I already wrote that, last paragraph. Is is not clear enough?

Comment: @Rakete1111: when you say, 'converts', one might think it's a cast. A cast from `int` to `bool` in VSCPP triggers this (imho totally pointless) warning. `bool operator!(int)` hides this 'conversion' from the user. Minor thing I agree, just to make it sure noone thinks that `!` should trigger this warning.

Comment: "You can apply ! to an int ... so there is no performance warning" -- non sequitur. In fact, VC++ certainly used to warn about exactly that. Don't know if it still does.